# hibernate ManyToOne ORM in java getting duplicate rows when persisting objects on the ONE side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, many-to-one

I am using H2 database and hibernate and I want to apply ORM with a relation manytoone.
my code:

```
    @Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ComputerComponent
{ @Id
    private final UUID id;
    //@Column(name = "category")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;
}

public ComputerComponent(ComputerComponentBuilder builder)
    {
        this.id = builder.id;
        this.category = builder.category;
        this.name = builder.name;
        this.brand = builder.brand;
        this.price = builder.price;
        this.quantity = builder.quantity;
        //this.category = category;

    }
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Category
{

    Category(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int category_id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<ComputerComponent> computerComponents = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

Now the problem is that when Im creating a cpu object which extends the Computer component, I have to persist the category object and the cpu object, but when persisting category object I am getting duplicate values (ex: id 1 -> CPU , id 2 -> CPU) which gives two categories with same name but different ID , which is not what I am looking for.

Main:

```
Category cpuCategory = new Category("CPU");
      Category cpuCategory2 = new Category("CPU");
      
      ComputerComponentBuilder builder = new ComputerComponentBuilder(UUID.fromString("d34dbb8a-6692-4e53-97db-345137c71bc3"), cpuCategory, "Intel Core i7-8809G", "Intel", 150, 25);
      builder.productLine("Core i7").numOfCores(4).prClockSpeed("3.10 GHz").grClockSpeed("1.20 GHz")
              .dimension("N/A").resolution("N/A").color("N/A").interfaceType("N/A").size("N/A");
      ComputerComponent cpu = builder.buildCpu();


      ComputerComponentBuilder builder2 = new ComputerComponentBuilder(UUID.fromString("d34dbb8a-6692-4e53-97db-345137c71bc4"), cpuCategory2, "Intel Core i7-8809G", "Intel", 150, 25);
      builder2.productLine("Core i7").numOfCores(4).prClockSpeed("3.10 GHz").grClockSpeed("1.20 GHz")
              .dimension("N/A").resolution("N/A").color("N/A").interfaceType("N/A").size("N/A");
      ComputerComponent cpu2 = builder2.buildCpu();
 em.persist(cpu);

 em.persist(cpu2);
em.persist(cpuCategory);
      em.persist(cpuCategory2);
```

---

Note that I can't create one cpuCategory object , because it doesn't make sense creating fixed objetc for each Item and passing it to the builder which will cause more code and algorythm.
Furthermore I want to do the same for the Brand field, but I'm still trying to find a solution for the Category issue.

Comment: You have to read the brand and pass it not create a new brand

Comment: @SimonMartinelli there is no way to create new brand/category and persist only unique values? because in my code I am using a builder which inside its constructor I pass the brand/category .
If what you mean is creating all the brands or categories that I will be using and then passing them in the constructor, then that will add too much lines to my code and more algprythm to know each computercomponent which category/brand object I shall pass with it.
note that the category/brand are info that I am originally getting from a csv file.

Comment: No that's not how JPA works

Comment: @SimonMartinelli okay so make sure I understood you well,lets take the example of Brand , if I want to persist them in database with the relation manytoone to Computercomponent, I have to read all Brands first and create a brand object, then I pass the brand object in constructor to each Computercomponent instance I am creating.
so if I have different ComputerComponents with same brand then I have to pass the same brand instance to the different computercomponents beinng created.

Comment: Yes or if you have the ID of the brand you can call EntityManager.getReference(id) instead of loading the data from the database